# "American" counterpart of anglophile

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

A person who is obsessed with British culture is an Anglophile.  Is there a word for a person who is obsessed with American culture (that is, the United States)?

Answer (score 20):

**Americanophile**, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Americanophile):

> a person who greatly admires or favors America or things from American culture

The word is also listen in the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/americanophile).

Attribution:"Americanophile." Merriam-Webster. Accessed April 09, 2018. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Americanophile.

Comment: Was just about to answer this :)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm embarrassed by how obvious the answer was ...

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed about considering how uncommon this word is. There may be a better one out there still.

Comment: I see many google results for Yankophile, but it's more slang-y.

Comment: @DylanBrams feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: @DylanBrams: Indeed, Yankophile doesn't appear to exist in books (e.g., more formal writing) at all: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Americanophile%2CYankphile%2CYankophile&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAmericanophile%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What about "`murican"?

Comment: @Bahrom that seems to be a derogatory term for Americans (so it excludes non-Americans who are very fond of the US).

Comment: @JJJ fair enough. I've never seen it used in a positive context.